# Subset of Accounts Object

Tags: custom-object, lookup

I'm trying to create an object that has a lookup to Accounts that will hold say 5 out of 25 accounts.  Then another custom object will have a lookup to only those 5 accounts.  My problem is the lookup populates with the custom_object__c's PK value.  Is there a way to have it lookup to an individual field on an object. Maybe with lookup filters?  The RM Accounts table will be the one end users can edit based on the lookups.  Below is an ERD on what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: Which tables are custom objects, and which are standard?

Comment: Account, Contact are standard objects.  Relationship Managers, Recruiters, ISO Accounts, and RM Accounts are Custom.

Comment: I currently have the RM Accounts object fields as lookups directly to Contact and Account.  Using a lookup filter to only show appropriate values.  With only 10 filters per field this isn't sustainable.  I tried to convince my boss to allow me to create a custom field that would depict a type of account and contact to make filtering easier, but he wants me to find a better way.